# How to build a specific revision with CruiseControl.NET and SVN

Tags: svn, cruisecontrol.net, ccnet-config

I am building my app using CruiseControl.NET and SVN. Currently my ccnet.config is configured to build the latest from SVN. I need to somehow change it to build a specific revision - Is that possible? I would guess adding a parameter to the svn-url below, but that's just a guess

My target looks like this:

```
<cb:scope>
<cb:define projectname="1.0 patch" />

<cb:define sldeployhttp.dir="\\xx.xx.xx.xx\qa" />
<cb:define sldeployhttps.dir="\\xx.xx.xx.xx\qa" />
<cb:define publishedeploy.dir="C:\Published\" />
<cb:define iispublishedeploy="PATCH" />
<cb:define iisPublished.dir ="PATCH"/>
<cb:define target="myproj-patch" />
<cb:define svn-viewname="1.0_Patch" />
<cb:define svn-url="http://myServer/branches/$(svn-viewname)" />
<cb:include href="$(svn-viewdir)\$(svn-viewname)\Build\Automation\foo.xml"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

My SVN mind is fading a little, but can't you get an old revision by tacking on a suffix at the end of the web url?

```
http://myServer/branches/$(svn-viewname)@333
```

Where 333 is the revision number.